# dir listing with path and total files filtered by date

Tags: powershell

Thanks in advance if you can help, I've searched here and found very close solutions but not exactly what I'm looking for...

What I need to do is this:

1. From a given directory, list files filtered by last modification date. I already know how to do that.
2. It needs to recurse into all sub-directories, and I can do that as well.
3. I'm looking for a listing that looks like this:

**File-count** of the files fitting the criteria.  **AbsolutePath**

So:

7815  C:\yadda\yaddayadda etc.

And if there's a way to insert something like " files in " instead of the space or tab, even better.

So the listing would look like:

14,627 files in C:\WildBehemoth

9,243 files in C:\TameBehemoth

etc...

Any ideas?
Thanks again!

Comment: try using the string format operator to build your string for each dir. this ... -f Format operator - PowerShell - SS64.com — https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html

Comment: It will help others if you can show your code or a sample if you have any.

Comment: Could you please share your code so far, it will be easier to find the part that you don't understand

Answer (score -1):

Create a custom object with the file count and the corresponding path, something like:

```
$output = @{ 
    filecount = 1000;
    path = "C:\..." 
}
```

Then pipe these objects to `Format-List` or `Format-table` cmdlets to print it in the way you prefer.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks so much everybody! I was able to resolve the problem and came up with this, single line in Powershell:

```
Get-Childitem -Path C:\PROGRA~2\beasts\ -Recurse -File | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-22)} | Group-Object directory | Select-Object count, name
```

The output I'm getting is exactly what I was looking for:

Count Name

2   C:\Program Files (x86)\beasts\largebeast\pachiderm

13   C:\Program Files (x86)\beasts\smallbeast\rodent

9631  C:\Program Files (x86)\beasts\tinybeast\gnat

So I have a count of files older than 21 days, and the absolute path to them next to the count.

Thanks again!